# How to Change Subclipse, history page ,Affected Path View's text color?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

[image]

I will thank you very much if you can tell me how can I change text color in the red box area of my picture.

My eclipse version is Indigo Service Release 2, and Build id is 20120216-1857.

The red box area is the affected Path View of subclipse history page.

[affected path view of subclips description here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/history_view.php)

Answer (score 0):

It probably should be an option, but I do not believe it is.

Note though that the way the formatting works is that it is based on the context of the history you are showing.  So if you asked to see the history of /trunk/src, as an example, and you look at a revision where the changed paths include files in /trunk/src, /trunk/docs and /trunk/tests, only the files from /trunk/src are "highlighted" and the others are all grayed out.  So one other solution is to open the History option from a higher point of your tree where all of the affected paths are children of that tree.

Comment: Thanks,I think I've got what you mean.But,maybe you didn't get mine.I  found that the color of PATH display black or grey on different computer when I opened the history option of the whole android project,I think perhaps it depends on the eclipse  version or the Subclipse version.Maybe I should try to update them.

Comment: You showed a screenshot of Subclipse and a link to a different product, Subversive.  The text is grey for the reasons I stated.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link,but thank you for answering.I will try to fix it when I  have time.